# How to get unicode character http response in blackberry?

Tags: http, blackberry, unicode

I have an api that response with json data which contains malayalam unicharacter and english unicharacter also.
it works fine in phonegap. but when i try to get this response in blackberry native (Java) i got different character response.

The response i got in phonegap and android native.

[image]

The response i got in blackberry 7 native.

[image]

how to solve this problem please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive the bytes, you will put them in a byte buffer.  Because this is JSON, you will then convert this to a String.  You probably just do this:

String jsonString = new String(jsonBytes);

But because the json data will probably be UTF-8 encoded, you actually need to do this:

String jsonString - new String(jsonBytes, "UTF-8");

I have assumed that your server is in fact using UTF-8 encoding.  Your server should set a header than specifies this.  You should really check for this in the response.  But I would guess UTF-8.

If this sort of thing is throwing you, I suggest you have search round for information on character encoding.  This might be a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8